# Add recovery partition back onto drive after drive change

Tags: macos, recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recreate Lion Recovery HD partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22284/how-to-recreate-lion-recovery-hd-partition)

I hope this question is different enough from the others that is doesn't get closed.

I am first time Mac user, long time Linux user, so pardon my ignorance in the Apple terminology.

I have a late 2011 MBP that I replaced the drive with an SSD.  I didn't care about the contents so I just stuck in the drive and Apple magically gave me OSX Lion again.  The SSD was too small, so I bought a bigger one and cloned the drive with SuperDuper.  It took a long time to boot afterwards, but it did so I thought everything was great.  Then I eventually noticed my recovery partition was not cloned with the rest of my data.

I still have the old drive with the recovery partition and I have enough space to add the partition back to the current/new drive.

My question is:  What is the easiest way to get my recovery partition back after losing it completely, without reinstalling from the internet (unless reinstalling won't mess with my data)?  I have a USB enclosure for the drive that has the partition.  I don't know if it matters, but I originally had Lion and upgraded to Mountain Lion.

Comment: What makes this different than the other questions - the other answers give a multitude of ways and "easy" depends on what you are comfortable with as opposed to some universal truth.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling over an existing system does not create a Recovery HD.

**WARNING: This is low level disk editing code and *will* hurt your disk if not done properly. Make sure you recheck your calculations on every calculator you own.**

You need to have a copy of Mountain Lion installer in your Applications folder for the following steps to work. Enter the following commands in Terminal, one by one, while following the [related video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=op7euNQmxgg). You need to fill all the `X` yourself by following the video.

> sudo -i
>
> diskutil list
>
> diskutil info /dev/diskXsX
>
> XXXXXXXXX-700*1024*1024=
>
> diskutil resizeVolume /dev/diskXsX XXXXXXXXXB jhfs+ “Recovery HD" 650002432B
>
> diskutil resizeVolume diskXsX 650002432B
>
> mkdir /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot
>
> hdiutil attach /Applications/Mac\ OS\ X\ Lion\ Installation.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
>
> cp /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/BaseSystem.dmg /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/
>
> cp /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/.disk_label /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/
>
> cp /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/boot.efi /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/
>
> cp /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/kernelcache /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/
>
> cp /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/
>
> cp /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/System/Library/CoreServices/PlatformSupport.plist /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/
>
> cp /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/
>
> umount -f /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/
>
> asr adjust —target /dev/diskXsX -settype "Apple_Boot"