# Can't Enable Filevault because Recovery Partition Missing

Tags: filevault, recovery

I'm trying to enable FileVault for my home directory on my Macbook, but every time I try it tells me it can't because the Recovery Partition is missing.

however, if I drop to a terminal and run "diskutil list", I do see the "Apple_Boot Recovery HD" partition of 650Mb, and I can boot into it at launch.

I have reFIND setup on this mac, to dual boot it with Ubuntu 12.10.  Any idea how to get past this ?

Comment: This might help http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52916/3973

Answer (score 2):

You will want to recreate the recovery partition following any of the answers here.

- [How to recreate Lion Recovery HD partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22284/how-to-recreate-lion-recovery-hd-partition)
- [How can I create or recreate a Lion recovery partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19145/how-can-i-create-or-recreate-a-lion-recovery-partition)

That ensures the installer will throw an error if you have an issue with the partition map (or better it might fix that issue for you). Since FileVault 2 takes over the whole drive, you might also be out of luck to convert the drive with the other partitions present. Worst case, you could remove the partitions that aren't standard and run the conversion. Just like the BootCamp assistant cannot carve space out when FileVault is enabled, the graphical tools might not allow coexistence of non HFS+ partitions or volumes.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable FileVault from terminal without having a recovery partition:

```
sudo fdesetup enable -defer /path/to/recovery/key.plist
```

[Source](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/12/20/managing-el-capitans-filevault-2-with-fdesetup/#more-7577)

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe there's been another [Recovery Disk Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202294) released since Mountain Lion.

You can re-run the same version of the installer and it will attempt to re-apply the recovery partition. For example, I'm on 10.11.6 so I'd download the 10.11.6 installer from the App Store and run it on top of my existing installation.