# JetDrive installation with missing Recovery partition: Clone internal SSD to external SSD

Tags: ssd, recovery

I have accidentally deleted my recovery partition (Yosemite) - no problem so far.

Now I have bought the JetDrive 725 and want to install it. I have to boot into the recovery mode and clone the internal SDD. Now this obviously won't work as I don't have any recovery partition anymore...

I have seen [How can I Create a Recovery Partition on a Newly Installed SSD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117954/how-can-i-create-a-recovery-partition-on-a-newly-installed-ssd) and the tip to do an internet recovery and install Yosemite over the existing installation. I am just a bit worried that this will change customizations / settings / installed programs / data.

I obviously have TimeMachine backups, although not all files due to space limitations.

What are the experiences with the internet recovery and to install Yosemite over an existing installation? How safe is it?

Alternatively, are there other options to clone my internal SSD to the new JetDrive SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) - which can also create [Recovery partitions](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/cloning-apples-recovery-hd-partition) - though it does need to get it from somewhere.

You can clone your boot drive whilst booted from it, with no issues.
Then just swap drives.

If you first clone without the Recovery partition option, you then have 2 identical drives to attempt the Internet Recovery on, with a full safety copy.

Recreate the Recovery Partition on either & CCC can then clone it to the other.

As far as I'm aware, the Internet Recovery should not mess up any settings - but this way is belt & braces.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach - I am just trying this and will report back.

Comment: Thanks a lot - worked perfectly! I did not try the creation of the rescue partition, though.