# Mavericks - Restore Damaged Recovery HD Partition without Reinstalling OS X

Tags: macos, startup, partition, install, recovery-hd

Recently, I tried to boot into the Recovery HD partition in order to perform some basic verify/repair operations using Disk Utility, only to find that my Recovery HD partition will not boot. Instead, I get a spinning progress indicator for 10 seconds before the computer shuts off. My computer (2012 rMBP, 10.9.1 Mavericks) boots into the main partition without issue.

Holding CMD+R causes the computer to boot directly to Internet Recovery, so the only way to access the Recovery HD is to hold Option when turning on the computer.  By pressing Shift when selecting Recovery HD, I was able to get the following error message:

```
Anonymous UUID:       (redacted)

Tue Feb  4 14:13:25 2014
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff80005cb7d4): "Process 1 exec of /sbin/launchd failed, errno 2"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/bsd/kern/kern_exec.c:3836
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81d3753df0 : 0xffffff8000222f69 
0xffffff81d3753e70 : 0xffffff80005cb7d4 
0xffffff81d3753ef0 : 0xffffff80005ab867 
0xffffff81d3753f10 : 0xffffff80005dfe51 
0xffffff81d3753f50 : 0xffffff8000220b2b 
0xffffff81d3753f80 : 0xffffff80002dc7d3 
0xffffff81d3753fa0 : 0xffffff80002f35d2 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: init
Boot args: -x

Mac OS version:
Not yet set

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: (redacted)
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (redacted)
```

My questions is this:  Is there some way to restore the Recovery HD partition without redownloading and reinstalling OS X Mavericks?

I've done the usual NVRAM reset and Disk Utility check, but nothing has worked. All the solutions I've managed to find were for Lion ([here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19145/how-can-i-create-or-recreate-a-lion-recovery-partition) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79831/how-to-restore-a-missing-recovery-hd-partition)), where it was possible to download the required Recovery HD files directly from Apple.

Comment: What is the big issue with using a new version?

Comment: There is no big issue... but it would save time, effort and bandwith.