# How can I make a recovery partition? ~OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos

Can i make a recovery partition for Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.1?

Also, If i upgrade to 10.9.2, will it delete the recovery partition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create or recreate a Lion recovery partition?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19145/how-can-i-create-or-recreate-a-lion-recovery-partition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- After making a partition with disk utility, you can run [this utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1433) from Apple to make it a recovery partition
- Upgrading your OS does not effect partitions other than the boot partition you upgraded.